# Numba's prange gives wrong result

Tags: python, numba

Updating a list in a prange loop gives wrong results when using prange compared to range.

```py
from numba import jit, prange
import numpy as np
@jit(parallel=True)
def prange_test(A):
    s = [0,0,0,0]
    b = 0.
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        s[i%4] += A[i]
        b += A[i]
    return s,b

def range_test(A):
    s = [0,0,0,0]
    b = 0.
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        s[i%4] += A[i]
        b += A[i]
    return s,b

A = np.random.random(100000)

print(prange_test(A))
print(range_test(A))
```

The sum b is the same, but the partial sum in s is wrong:

```py
(array([7013.98962611, 6550.90312863, 7232.49698366, 7246.53627734]), 49955.32870429267)
([12444.683249345742, 12432.449908902432, 12596.461028432543, 12481.734517611982], 49955.32870429247)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's a little unclear in the documentation, you cannot safely accumulate into an array-like object when you are writing to the same data elements from different iterations of a `prange` parallel loop. This [github issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3681), that I actually submitted earlier this year asks about this specific issue.

The fact that this has been raised again reminds me that I want to submit a PR to the numba docs to clarify this.